# How do I introduce my new kittens to my roommate's dog?

Tags: cats, dogs, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets

I decided to adopt two Maine Coon - Siamese cat mixes since they were bonded and I did not want to separate them. My roommate has had a Cavalier King Charles Spaniel for the past two years and he has been really gentle and relaxed. I figured that if I adopted two kittens who have spent time in a household with a dog, there wouldn't be any real issues when they meet.

However, when I brought them home, the dog immediately started barking and the kittens seem to try to stay away from the dogs. The dog seems a bit anxious, even when I have restricted the cats to a room so that they can get used to their new environment. Is there anything I can do to help the dog relax? He can clearly smell them in the room and keeps barking outside of it.

Comment: Did you do the introductions outside on "neutral" ground? If you took them directly into the house the dog is reacting as I would expect it to. It's his territory and he's defending it. Don't know if you can recover the introduction at this point but you may want to try having them meet outside somewhere that isn't the yard or a place where the dog normally goes.

Comment: How long has it been since you brought the kittens home?

Comment: It has just been a couple of hours. Right now they are in my room, where the dog usually doesn't come and generally isn't allowed. I have kept the door closed as well. Unfortunately, I did do it inside the house and when the dog got close to the cats, they tried to bat him away. Do you guys have any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: From the cat perspective, keeping them isolated in their 'safe room' is the best way to proceed. They have just been put into a territory that has the scent of another predator and they can't escape, they now need some time to adjust and evaluate their situation. They will show when they are ready to explore the territory, ideally you'd give them a chance to get to know the dog by introducing his scent into their room, i.e. rub a towel on the dog and put it in there. Best if they can smell the dog, without the dog making a ruckus, so better to use towel instead of barking dog at the door.

Comment: Thank you! What can I do for the dog, who seems very anxious about the situation?